# Postgresql grant command syntax

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble with the syntax to grant a developer the ability to create or replace a function.  The syntax guide doesn't seem to show how to do this. Can anyone provide the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, still earning the reps for comments.

Can you please share your GRANT statement and the complete error message?

I created a test table with a few rows of data, and a test function that returns a rowcount on the test table.

I granted execute to user2 with no errors:

*grant execute on function f_totrecords() to user2 with grant option ;*

It's in the docs - search the page for "function" and notice the "with grant option" in the syntax:
[GRANTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html)

GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { FUNCTION function_name ( [ [ argmode ] [ arg_name ] arg_type [, ...] ] ) [, ...]
         | ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]